# Plugin readme.txt and assets internationalization

Tags: plugins, localization

I've learnt [how to internationalize my plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/), but that does not seem to cover documentation (readme.txt), screenshots and banners (assets).

I'd like to present localized versions of those as well, is it feasible?

Comment: You mean translation on wordpress.org plugin repository or alternate readme in different languages in the plugin directory?

Comment: @bueltge I mean translation on plugin repository and possibly alternate screenshots and banners since they contain text which I'd like to internationalize

Comment: Ok, then is the right way to use the translation option via GlotPress on each plugin. You find all relevant hints in this post https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/tools/glotpress-translate-wordpress-org/ In short, on each plugin you have a translation link and that give all users the chance to contribute translations.

Comment: @bueltge Thanks'I'll have a look. However, I already have the translations and I'd just like to somehow  upload them... Will try GlotPress options anyhow

Comment: @bueltge Your guidance was correct. My plugin is now being translated.. When you want to write an answer, I guess I'll upvote and accept

Comment: Fine, that I can help. You should add the hint for the translation on the repository, that my answer is clear mapped to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the translation option via "GlotPress" on each plugin in the official plugin repository. You find all relevant hints in [this post](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/tools/glotpress-translate-wordpress-org/) of the make blog at wordpress.org.

In short, on each plugin you have a translation link and that give all users the chance to contribute translations.